# ExtentReports causing failure when Selenium Job is run through Ant

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ant, testng

I am running a simple testNG test with Ant.
The test is failing with the message `[testng] The tests failed.`

However, it runs fine without Ant (when I am running from `testng.xml`)

```
public class extentreportWithAnt {
  WebDriver driver;
  ExtentReports extent;
  ExtentTest test;

  @Test
  public void installapp() {
    ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports("D:\\report\\ext_rep_check.html");
    test = extent.startTest(ExtentWithAnt");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/");
    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Trip advison opened");
    extent.endTest(test);
    extent.flush();
    extent.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any error as such in your code block. Can you consider showing us how you configured the Test within `Ant`? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

I don't see any major issue as such in your code block. But you may consider setting up the absolute path of `geckodriver` through `System.setProperty` in your code block. You may consider to keep the Testname **"ExtentWithAnt"** within double quotes. Finally you may consider to open the report page in the same url as well.

Here is your own code with some tweaks in it:

```
package ExtentReport_V_2_05;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class Q44244984_extent_reports_V2 
{

  WebDriver driver;
  ExtentReports extent;
  ExtentTest test;

  @Test
  public void installapp() 
  {

  ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports("D:\\report\\ext_rep_check.html");
  test = extent.startTest("ExtentWithAnt");
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/");
  test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Trip advison opened");
  extent.endTest(test);
  extent.flush();
  extent.close();
  driver.get("file:///D:/report/ext_rep_check.html");
  }
}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.